# Monster Stacking Puzzle Game?

Tags: identify-this-game

A couple of years ago I bought a game that I absolutely adored. Unfortunately I lent it to a friend, never got it back and haven't been able to find it since. Can anyone help? I don't know the name of it, but basically it was a white plastic case that the little see through monsters could be stored in but it was also the game board. The monsters were red, blue and green and they could be stacked on top of one another, but only in a certain order. The aim of the game was that you would start with the monsters set up in a certain pattern and then had to work out how to move and stack them into a single pile.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.passionforpuzzles.com/puzzles/cannibal-monsters-logic-puzzle

Cannibal Monsters is your game maybe?